# Installing MongoDB on a Raspberry Pi - -bash: mongo: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, raspberry-pi

I'm using a tutorial to install MongoDB on the raspberry pi: http://notejs.com/?p=252

I have followed the instructions with complete success up till the line:

Connect to an instance:

`mongo`

I then get an error like this:

> -bash: mongo: command not found

I have followed this tutorial step by step, the only difference is that I downloaded, compiled and installed MongoDB in a folder that isn't the home folder, could this be the problem?

edit: MongoDB is apparently running already when I enter the command: 
`sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start`

So it's not the case that it's too much for my PI

Comment: check if you have mongo command exists in your compilation folder? Though you can install MongoDB on Raspberry pi but its too  much for it.

Comment: Check your $PATH - `mongo` should be in one of those directories, or your can add onto your PATH to point to where the `mongo` command resides.

Comment: How do I check $PATH in linux?

Comment: `echo $PATH` This will display your PATH variable and show you the directories your commands reside in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions have this section for making the `mongod` binary part of your path, which is why that is working:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/mongo/bin/mongod /usr/bin/mongod
```

But they do not do the same for the `mongo` shell binary.  Hence you just need to do the same thing for the that binary, that is:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/mongo/bin/mongo /usr/bin/mongo
```

Alternatively you could add `/opt/mongo/bin` to your $PATH variable, or just call `/opt/mongo/bin/mongo`directly.